# Calabash iOS error when I try to run the test suite: uninitialized constant Calabash::Cucumber::VERSION

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

When I try to run my test suite I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant Calabash::Cucumber::VERSION (NameError)
/Users/Dexter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:1041:in `check_server_gem_compatibility'
/Users/Dexter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:645:in `relaunch'
/Users/Dexter/Work/mobile-calabash-test/features/ios/support/01_launch.rb:55:in `Before'
```

These are my paths before I run the test suite:

```
export APP=prebuilt/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/leeo-cal.app
export APP_BUNDLE=$APP
cucumber -p ios
```

This is my `config.yml`

```
ios: PLATFORM=ios -r features/support -r features/ios/support
```

This is the `Before` in my `01_launcher.rb`

```
Before do |scenario|
  scenario_tags = scenario.source_tag_names
  reset_between_scenario = !scenario_tags.include?('@tandem_scenario')

  if reset_between_scenario
    if LaunchControl.target_is_simulator?
      target = LaunchControl.target
      simulator = RunLoop::Device.device_with_identifier(target)
      bridge = RunLoop::Simctl::Bridge.new(simulator, ENV['APP'])
      bridge.reset_app_sandbox
    else
      LaunchControl.install_app_on_physical_device
    end
  end

  launcher = Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher.launcher
  unless launcher.calabash_no_launch?
    launcher.relaunch
    launcher.calabash_notify(self)
  end
end
```

I'm not really sure what's going on. Is a file not being loaded correctly?

This is the gist to the `01_launch.rb` file: https://gist.github.com/DexterV/94b0853e8f784171adce

Comment: Great question!  Woot!  Can you provide the rest of of 01_launch?  Either in a gist or appended to this question.

Comment: Hi @jmoody! I've added in the gist link! Thank you =].

Comment: The 01_launch looks good.  Can I see the env.rb?  Are you a Xamarin customer?  This app looks familiar.  If so, can you contact me via my GitHub profile?

Comment: Hi @jmoody. If this is a known issue, can you please add a workaround to the answer section below? I"m seeing this problem too.

Comment: It is not a known issue and I cannot reproduce.  Can you post your 01_launch and the exact command you are using to run cucumber?